# AWS Cognito AdminLinkProviderForUser tries to update immutable user attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml

I would like to link new user who is using SSO with the existing cognito user. In order to achieve this, cognito has AdminLinkProviderForUser endpoint. But this endpoint returns error below and I cannot change the user attribute configuration since Cognito does not allow me.

```
Cannot update attribute: custom:someCustomAttribute: Attribute cannot be updated.
 (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: Xxxxxxxxxx; Proxy: null):
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InvalidParameterException: Cannot update attribute: custom:someCustomAttribute: Attribute cannot be updated.
```

Is there any other way to link SAML based federated SSO user with the existing cognito (username-password) user?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted with AWS regarding this and apparently there is no rollback if you have created an immutable user attribute so we are going to end up re-creating the users in order to link them.

Comment: Hey thanks for following up! I'm facing the same issue. How would you re-create a user to link them? Can we do the link as part of SignUpcommand? Doesn't this sign out the user among other issues? I think I'd rather create an identical attribute that is mutable and use that going forward. Why does AdminLinkUser touch these attributes anyway?

Comment: Hey @boy 
First of all, I had to create new identical `mutable` user attribute to replace the immutable cognito user attributes and updated all the users to avoid InvalidParameterException during the linking operation. Why AdminLinkUser touch this is a mystery for me too.. About the re-creation, I have a python script to re-create the user, which calls a backend endpoint and this endpoint creates the user with new mutable attributes and does other operations like sending email etc.